# Markdown with a space

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, markdown

I want to have a space between each use example using markdown.

Example: `.ban Tim`, `.ban Henry`, `.ban Louis`

```
.setDescription(`**Utilisation :** \`${settings.prefix}${command.help.name} ${command.help.usage}\`\n**Exemple :** \`${settings.prefix}${command.help.name} ${command.help.exemple.join(', ')}\``);
```

Comment: Can you show your current output

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: ``.config logChannel #logs, prefix ?, welcomeMessage Bienvenue !`` without  white space

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the full statement in backticks, map the examples with the command, then join with surrounding backticks.

```js
let cmd = '.ban'
console.log('`'+['Tim', 'Henry', 'Louis'].map(v => cmd + ' ' + v).join('`, `')+'`')
```